# How do you find “issued by” and “issued in” on a Nigeria passport? It’s required for a visa application

Tags: schengen, schengen-visas

Q1. How do I get the Issued by and Issued in on my passport? Note I have a Nigeria  passport and it only has Authority, which is ABUJA HQRS.

I am planing on visiting a friend in Germany for 34 days, the Netherlands 4 days, and the Czech Republic 4 days.

Q2. The Member state of first entry: Germany. I was told to fill in the main travel destination(s): Germany only, and that I should not include the Netherlands and the Czech Republic as well (even if I am travelling to other Schengen countries). Is that correct? I need information on how to correctly fill the form.

[image: Here is a copy of my passport][image: I was old to fill it like this][image][image: I was told to remove the Netherlands and the Czech Republic]

Comment: Please keep to one question per question. I think here the main one is how to find 'issued by' and 'issued in'.  You can ask additional questions for the other bits but the '4 days other countries' has been asked and answered before. With 34 days in Germany, just add those countries to the itinerary and apply in Germany.

Comment: @Willeke So its very wrong for me to asked more than 1 question at a time?

Comment: It is against the rules on all Stack Exchange site, because only one answer can be accepted as the right answer, but with two questions in one, you will likely not get one answer in which both sub-questions are answered best.

Comment: @Willeke Thank you very much, I do that understand now, Are you saying that it is allowed to fill Germany being my main and first port of entry and exit, as well as Netherlands and Czech?

Comment: @ChowLu You should feel free to ask a new question about that, but first search the site to see if a similar question has already been answered. (It has.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My answer is based on Ghanaian Passport, which I believe is not that different from Nigeria’s.

The “ issued by” also known as issuing authority , is the Passport Office and the “issued in” is place the passport was issued which in my case is Accra.

Comment: That is correct. I also used a Ghanaian passport same as Nigerian passport. In any case they are not hard and fast about the _issued by_. I have also written Ghana Government and Ghana Embassy, Washington etc before and had no problems. Regarding the travel destinations, on the paper based one I used to enter all my destinations. The French, German and Spanish embassies in Washington DC actually requested a letter with your itinerary with days to be spent in each country.

Comment: @TheZealot, if you can put this as an answer it can be up-voted and maybe accepted.